# Sitecore 930 installation issue with parameter name Credential

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect

I'm trying to install Sitecore 9.3.0 using SIA: https://tothecore.sk/2019/11/28/installing-sitecore-9-3-using-sitecore-install-assistant-sia/ and I keep getting this error:

> [------------ XConnectXP0_CreateShards : Command
>   -----------------------------] [ShardingTool - Create]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
>
> [ XConnectXP0_CreateShardApplication... : InvokeSqlcmd
>   ------------------------] A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'. This error might have been caused by
>   applying the default parameter binding. You can disable the default
>   parameter binding in $PSDefaultParameterValues by setting
>   $PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"] to be $true, and then trying
>   again. The following default parameters were successfully bound for
>   this cmdlet when the error occurred: -Debug -WarningAction -Verbose
>   -InformationAction -ErrorAction

Have anyone encoutered this issue?

Comment: I also tried setting up the param value: $PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"] = $true

Comment: Are you installing using Azure SQL?

Comment: No, I am installing it on my dev machine. The below answer is the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the task that it is failing for you during the installation process:

```
"CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLoginInvokeSqlCmd": {
            "Description": "Create Collection Shard Database Server Login.",
            "Type": "InvokeSqlcmd",
            "Params": {
                "ServerInstance": "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                "Credential": "[variable('Sql.Credential')]",
                "InputFile": "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLogin')]",
                "Variable": [
                    "[concat('UserName=',variable('SqlCollection.User'))]",
                    "[concat('Password=',variable('SqlCollection.Password'))]"
                ]
            },
            "Skip": "[parameter('SkipDatabaseInstallation')]"
        }
```

This task uses the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command.

According to the accepted answer on this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622424/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-with-get-credential-doesnt-work), it seems that your issue might be caused by the fact that Microsoft has two versions of `Invoke-Sqlcmd`:

1. The Database Engine - no -Credentials parameter.
2. The SqlServer module - -Credentials parameter is available.

And one of them doesn't use the `-Credentials` parameter.

As suggested, try to run the following command to install the correct module on your machine:

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
```

And then try the installation process again.

Comment: Thank you Alessandro, this solved my problem

Comment: Thanks! One other note for anyone encountering this issue, you may need to close/restart your console app/window (depending on the console you use) after installing the new SqlServer PS module in order for the installer to use the new module.

Comment: One another notes for anyone who has more than one version of PowerShell installed then, you need to install module to correct PowerShell version.