# Getting below error while installing sitecore 10.1

Tags: xconnect

`Install-SitecoreConfiguration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TrustServerCertificate'`. This error might have been caused by applying the
default parameter binding. You can disable the default parameter binding in `$PSDefaultParameterValues` by setting `$PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"] to be $true`, and
then trying again. The following default parameters were successfully bound for this cmdlet when the error occurred: -Debug -WarningAction -Verbose -InformationAction
-ErrorAction
At `C:\Source\eKeystoneHelix\KAO\Installation\install-xp0.ps1:109 char:1`

- Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
  ```

Comment: Are you using powershell script or graphical setup?

Comment: did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/sitecore-930-installation-issue-with-parameter-name-credential